CalledProcessError.stderr of subprocess.check_call is None despite the process outputting an error message
I'm trying to capture the error message of a program called by subprocess.check_call but the stderr in the error object is always None.
Here is a short script that shows this:
import subprocess
import sys

if '--fail' in sys.argv:  # the script calls itself with this option, for the test
    print('this is the error message', file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)

try:
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, sys.argv[0], '--fail'],
                          stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    print('Not failed?')  # this neither happens nor is expected
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as err:
    if err.stderr:
        print(err.stderr.decode())  # this is what I expect
    else:
        print('<No error message>')  # this is what happens

I have Python 3.10.12.

You didn't communicate with the subprocess at all, so the content is still buffered in the pipe.
The docs of check_call have this notice:

Note: Do not use stdout=PIPE or stderr=PIPE with this function.

Instead of this:
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, sys.argv[0], '--fail'],
                      stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

Use the higher level API of run:
subprocess.run([sys.executable, sys.argv[0], '--fail'],
               capture_output=True, check=True)


Seriously it doesn't raise an error if an illegal argument is passed?
Anyway, I think the equivalent code to mine would still have stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, since the output may be very long and I don't need it. The only necessary changes are check_call -> run and an addition of check=True, right?

I showed the top-level interface. If you're going to use a pipe and a lower-level interface to the subprocess, then you need to read output from the process's stdout/stderr somehow. In that case I'd recommend using Popen and communicate.

What would be an advantage of Popen? As far as I can say, in my case, it's just run with extra steps.

The pipe buffer can only hold 64kb. What's the problem with capture_output=True? You want to avoid combining stdout/stderr?

In my specific case, stdout can be very long and I don't want to see it (nor save it anywhere). I only need the error message that is a few lines at most.

@PiotrSiupa Yeah, in that case specifying stdout and stderr instead should be fine.
